# Specific authentification for a website

Tags: siteminder

I have two website and both are on the same domain (ex: http://test.com/). For the first site (ex: http://test.com/app1)  I want to have SiteMinder check if the user is logged in or not, but on the second website (ex: http://test.com/app2) I do not want this check to be performed.

My question here is: is this thing possible or the second website must be on a different domain ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  You should create a realm for /app1 (don't user / root protection), and no realm for /app2.  If you want root protection at / except for /app2, then create an unprotected realm for /app2.